# How to display data repeater control in win-form?

Tags: c#, winforms, datarepeater

i am using windows applications. in that form i am using DataRepeater control.
i display numbers in that control. (vs 2010)

**My code**

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("c1");
                dt.Rows.Add("1");
                dt.Rows.Add("2");
                dt.Rows.Add("3");
                dt.Rows.Add("4");
                dt.Rows.Add("5");
                dt.Rows.Add("6");
                dt.Rows.Add("7");
                dt.Rows.Add("8");
                dt.Rows.Add("9");
                dt.Rows.Add("10");
                textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "c1");
                dataRepeater1.DataSource = dt;
```

i changed a Layoutstyle is Horizontal that time it display all numbers
in row. But my aim is one row display only 6 numbers after that 7th
number onwards it display next row. similarly to all numbers.

How to do this?..

Any ideas are welcome.

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to package the 6 number batches into another class:

```
class Batch
{
    public int One {get;set;}
    // etc
}
```

And give the data repeater a list of these:

```
var l = new List<Batch>();
dataRepeater1.DataSource = l;
```

Your repeater will then need controls inside it that look at the properties on the `Batch` class.  The class wrapper is required because the repeater will repeat for each item in a collection (row in a `DataTable` for example) so to group them, you need to do that manually.

Further reading:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2009/08/12/datarepeater-control-for-windows-forms.aspx